# Convert Raw Data "AnyObject?" to NSData or String

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I have been stuck for the last few days on this and have read countless posts here on Stackoverflow and across the web, but am still a little lost. (by the way I am a bit of a newbie in Swift).

i have the following code

`Alamofire.request(.GET, "url")
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in 
             printIn(data)}`

This prints out a long string of numbers in the Console, which is perfect, exactly what I need.

However I now would like to iterate through these and get the number at certain index's, so would like to convert this into a string or NSData.

I have tried many different ways but have not yet found how to do this, if somebody could please help me I would be very grateful.

I have tried using

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "url")
    .responseString(encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
        println(data)
    }
```

but this only prints out a jumbled up mess.

many thanks

Chris

Comment: If the println(data) in your first code sample prints the data in an acceptable form, you could try to use data.description to get a string form and save the result in a variable.

Comment: The problem is when I try to work with "data" it throws up the 'Anyobject?' error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say:

> However I now would like to iterate through these and get the number at certain index's, so would like to convert this into a string or `NSData`.

When you use `response`, the `data` parameter actually *is* a `NSData`. So just cast the variable to the appropriate type, and you should be in business, e.g.:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        if let data = data as? NSData {
            for i in 0 ..< data.length {
                var byte: UInt8!
                data.getBytes(&byte, range: NSMakeRange(i, 1))
                print(String(format: "%02x ", byte))
            }
        }
}
```

In my example loop, just logging the hex string representation of the `byte` variable, but it's a numeric value with which you can do whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

The data is NSData and ascii encoded (in your 2nd example)

```
let s = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
```

in the first case you don't specify an encoding and so it defaults to NSUTF8

```
let s = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```